# How to locate and debug WordPress Snippet

Tags: wordpress, code-snippets, wordpress-rest-api

In my WordPress project i have a snippet, configured to "Run snippet everywhere".
But it seems the code of my snippet isn't working correctly, so i wish i could debug it.

My snippet is a PHP function.

So i open my web page with chrome console. I searched a long time, i cannot find the snippet code on the sources.

After a search on my server files, i found the code in this folder :

```
public_html\wp-content\cache\object\144\36a\14436a0e413a60c35b3bbe4fcbfaafec.php
```

But i cant access to the "cache" folder when I run the website with chrome console. This folder isn't visible.

Could you help me to localize the file, so i can debug it ?

Thanks !!

For information, this is the code of my snippet :

```
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
if ( isset( $_GET['clear-cart'] ) ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(true);
    
    //WC()->cart->empty_cart(true);
}
```

Comment: PHP is run on the server. You can't see your snippet or debug it from your browser debugger.

Comment: I normally debug WordPress by writing things to the error log and reading that, e.g. `error_log('calling empty_cart')` or `error_log(print_r($variable_to_dump, true));` There may be better ways, e.g. attaching an IDE to the remote PHP process on the server, but that's much harder to set up.

Comment: (P.S. 'localize' normally means 'translate strings into the user's language', not 'run locally')